# Deploy React app using create-react-app to github pages isn't working

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have a github action set up that builds my react app and commits the build directory to the gh-pages branch of my repo. I then set github pages to serve that branch but i'm getting a problem where all of my static files are returning 404.

here's my console output when visiting my github pages site

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.
thatnerduknow.github.io/:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/static/css/2.0a9ec390.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
thatnerduknow.github.io/:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/static/css/main.8e6a535e.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
thatnerduknow.github.io/:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/static/js/main.6b85f889.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
thatnerduknow.github.io/:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/static/js/2.e6086643.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
thatnerduknow.github.io/:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/static/js/2.e6086643.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
thatnerduknow.github.io/:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/static/js/main.6b85f889.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
favicon.ico:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/favicon.ico 404
manifest.json:1 GET https://thatnerduknow.github.io/manifest.json 404
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I've had a similar problem with one of my vue applications where I had to set the public path config varialbe to "" but setting my homepage in package.json (I checked the Create React App documentation and it says that's where it looks to set the public path variable) to "" it still gives me this error.

Comment: Could you please set `"homepage":"thatnerduknow.github.io"` in package.json and try it.

Comment: That didn't work but `"https://thatnerduknow.github.io/ThatNerdUKnow/"` worked

Answer (score 1):

Change homepage path in package.json

`"homepage":"https://thatnerduknow.github.io/ThatNerdUKnow/"`